# Odd int-to-string issue?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have this code:

```
NSString *hString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (h * 100)];
    HField.text = hString;
```

H is 0.721.

HField.text now reads:

1073741824

Any ideas why this isn't giving me 72?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah. The problem is that `h` seems to be a `double` or `float`. Try this:

```
HField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", (h * 100.0)];
```

This should work. You have to use `%f` for floating-point numbers and `%d` for integers.

## Edit

```
HField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", (NSInteger) round(h * 100.0)];
```

Round will round the float to an integer. You can alternately use `ceil()` or `floor()` to round up or down, respectively. The `(NSInteger)` cast is there to make sure it is converted to an integer.

Comment: This works, except it now returns it as a float. Is there a way to do this same thing but return it as an integer instead?

Answer (score 3):

Probably because if `h` is 0.721 it is a `float` or a `double`, which means that the product is a float or a double, which means that you should cast it to `int` first or use `%f`.

Answer (score 2):

with `%d` you are refering to an integer

try `%f` instead:

```
NSString *hString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", (h * 100)];
```